# Why is $ \lim_{x\to0}\frac{2-\sqrt{4-x}}{x} = \frac{1}{4} $?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

$$
\lim_{x\to0} \frac{2-\sqrt{4-x}}{x} = \frac{1}{4}
$$

Whether completing-the-square nor adding-zero helped me converting this equation into something useful. In the end, there is always one $x$ that 'zeros' my terms. I'm sure I've tried every possible trick I know. Still, there must be some technique left. What did I miss?

Comment: Notice that $2^2-4=0$ ;)

Comment: Or maybe I've just done too much math recently...

Comment: That was a hint to rationalizing. ^^

Comment: Multiply both numerator and denominator by $2+\sqrt{(4-x)}$

Comment: @Mann this does not help here. But thanks. ;)

Comment: @user1511417 It does

Comment: You can also use L'Hôpital's rule.

Comment: How many more answers saying the same thing do we need?

Comment: Just a note: $2+\sqrt{4-x}$ is called the conjugate of $2-\sqrt{4-x}$ (so just the - changed into a +). This multiplication results in a product of the form $(a+b)*(a-b)=a^2-b^2$, which is a lot easier to deal with.

Comment: Think about the definition of the derivative of $x\mapsto \sqrt{4-x}$ at $0$ and see how it relates to your limit.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

$$\frac{2-\sqrt{4-x}}{x}=\frac{2-\sqrt{4-x}}{x}\frac{2+\sqrt{4-x}}{2+\sqrt{4-x}}=\frac{2^2-(4-x)}{x\cdot(2+\sqrt{4-x})}=\frac{1}{2+\sqrt{4-x}}$$

Comment: Hm? 2² - 4 - 0 is 0  and 0*(2+....) is also 0

Comment: @user1511417 The 4s cancel on the numerator to 0, and then the $x$ on top and bottom cancel

Comment: Ah I see your point. .. ok

Answer (score 5):

Let $y>0$ be such that $y^2=4-x$, then
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{2-\sqrt{4-x}}x=\lim_{y\to 2}\frac{2-y}{4-y^2}=\lim_{y\to 2}\frac{2-y}{(2-y)(2+y)}=\lim_{y\to 2}\frac1{2+y}=\frac14$$

Comment: That's an interesting method.

Comment: Gosh! This is ingenious!

Answer (score 2):

You can use $(a+b)(a-b) = a^2-b^2$ and get

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{4-4+x}{x(2+\sqrt{4-x})} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1}{2+\sqrt{4-x}}.$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

Do you see why this limit is the same of

$$ \lim \limits_{x \rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{2+ \sqrt{4-x}}?$$

Comment: No, I am sorry.

Comment: See Volodymyr's comment.